# Android with GoogleMap About mapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

As we all know, if we want to use google maps api. We can use target:Google apis;
But some rom just my moblie phone that has no google map.

If i use mapActivity it will tell me "class not found".
And it work well in another Phone. (It ensure my code is correct.)

And someone say this problem is with the "framework" missing a file in my Rom.

But when I install Goole map.apk on these phones, the Google maps work fine on them.

I do not know why the google map can run on my phone, but my application will not run on my phone that uses mapAcivity.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first sentence in your question. Can you please re-write that?

Answer (score 0):

try to use Google APIs like a target of your project.

Comment: I have set  target  ：Google APIs